# Stripping the time out of an NSDate

Tags: cocoa, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have seen many version of the following code to remove the time element from an NSDate.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
unsigned int intFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:intFlags fromDate:now];

NSDate *today = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
```

Trouble is it does not work as expected. I am currently in British summertime (BST). If I run this code now, now=@"2012-07-07 19:24:06 +0000"

today=@"2012-07-06 23:00:00 +0000"

What I want to see is today=@"2012-07-07 00:00:00 +0000"

I can only guess that it has something to do with daylight saving. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting midnight BST (which is GMT+1 hour), which is the same as 23:00 GMT (+0000).

[NSDate date] will return a date in the current timezone, so your date is in BST. Have you also tried setting the timezone to GMT:

```
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I must admit though, it seems really counter intuitive. The "now" date above is in BST... In my original code, what is being returned is, as you say, a GMT date. Setting the component timezone to GMT just seems odd. Will that work from any timezone - i.e.: if now was in EST?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that the "now" date above is indeed in GMT.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a date without a time, because there never was a point in time that did not have a time (according to our current calendaring systems, anyway), and a date is just a point in time.  Ergo, a date necessarily *must* have a time.

What you *can* do, is *format* a date such that the time isn't displayed.  For that, you use an `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];

NSDate *todayAtMidnight = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

NSString *formatted = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:todayAtMidnight dateStyle: NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
// "formatted" is now something like "Jul 8, 2012". 
// It varies according to your locale and user settings.
```

Technically the first bit (of setting the time portion to midnight) isn't necessary if you're just formatting a date without the time, but you can leave it in if it makes you feel like you're actually "removing the time".  :)

Comment: Thanks for the input... What I want to do is store the dates then compare them down the line without worrying about the time portion of the date... I realise I could ignore the time element during the comparison step, but this seems inefficient, which why I wanted to set the time to midnight for each date I store.

Answer (score 0):

Add a

```
[components setHour:0];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];
```

to avoid the use of the default values. Documentation doesn't even say what these values are, so they might not be "0".

Comment: Sorry... no difference. I have even tried subtracting the time values by stripping them out from now into a component and subtracting - same result each time